# Configuring properties/attributes mentioned in standalone.xml in spring boot

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot

I'm building a new application using Spring boot and trying to configure *name* and *value* properties in *module-option* attribute from an existing application as shown below:
`<security-domain name="someDomainName">`
   `<authentication>`
        `<login-module code="someClassName" module="someModule">`
           `<module-option name="someName" value="someValue"/>`
        `</login-module>`
   `</authentication>`
`</security-domain>`

Now, how do I configure the above properties mentioned in standalone.xml (where JBoss application server is used) in Spring-Boot (note I'm using Apache Tomcat web server).

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean how to set `properties` or how to define a `bean` of some type/class?

Comment: setting properties.

Answer (score -1):

From what i understand from the comment you want to create and use properties in your new spring boot java configuration. The best practice of spring boot to create and set properties is creating a `bean` for them as the following:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my")
public class MyProperties {
    private String myFirstProperty;

    public String getMyFirstProperty() {
        return this.myFirstProperty;
    }

    public void setMyFirstProperty(String myFirstProperty) {
        this.myFirstProperty = myFirstProperty;
    }
}
```

Now if you place the property `my.my-first-property=value` in `application.properties` that should be located in `src/main/resources` spring boot will automaticaly pick properties by the defined prefix (`my` in this case) and try to match them with the `bean` annotated with `@ConfigurationProperties`.

After doing that you can inject this bean anywhere in your java configuration to use the properties as a standard POJO.

You can now use this bean to create more complex configuraiton with classes,enums,lists,maps etc and I recommend using YAML syntax by changing `application.properties` to `application.yml`

More information: [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)

**EDIT:** Example how to use the properties in a configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final MyProperties myProperties;

    public WebSecurityConfig(MyProperties myProperties) { // inject the property class using constructor injections
        this.myProperties = myProperties;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .ldapAuthentication()
                .userDnPatterns(myProperties.getMyFirstProperty()) // here i use a property loaded from external source (application.properties/yml)
                .groupSearchBase("ou=groups")
                .contextSource(contextSource())
                .passwordCompare()
                    .passwordEncoder(new LdapShaPasswordEncoder())
                    .passwordAttribute("userPassword");
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks @Tom for the solution but I was able to figure out that what I'm looking for is LDAP server access. The [link](https://spring.io/guides/gs/authenticating-ldap/) has partially helped me in achieving my objective.  
The place where I'm stuck now is how to pass module-option properties to a class using the configure method described in the link.

Comment: What you can do is use the mechanism i mentioned above to create your properties, then inject and use this class in your `WebSecurityConfig`. I will edit my answer with an example.

Comment: Thanks @Tom for the revert. Shall discuss the same with LDAP API developers.

Comment: No problem, glad i could help a bit. I integrated spring security to LDAP and AD so if you have any questions i can try to help in that as well